# How to construct a convenient iterator over blocks of Matrix using Eigen

Tags: c++, iterator, eigen

I want to construct a "block-columnwise" iterator which runs over all possible blocks of of Dense Matrix with Eigen.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
    Eigen::MatrixXd A(4,4);
    A << 1,2,3,4,
        5,6,7,8,
        9,10,11,12,
        13,14,15,16;

    for (Eigen::Index k=0; k< ? ; ++k) {
       //?????
       Eigen::Iterator it.... ;
       std::cout<<it<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output should be:

```
1 2
5 6

9 10
13 14

3 4
7 8

11 12
15 16
```

Essentially, I'm searching a nice version of

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
    Eigen::MatrixXd A(4,4);
    A << 1,2,3,4,
        5,6,7,8,
        9,10,11,12,
        13,14,15,16;

    int numberOfBlocksPerDir =2;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBlocksPerDir ; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < numberOfBlocksPerDir ; j++) {
        Eigen::Block<Eigen::MatrixXd, 2, 2> currentBlock = A.block<2, 2>(numberOfBlocksPerDir * j, numberOfBlocksPerDir  * i);
        std::cout<<currentBlock <<std::endl;
      }
  }
}
```

Is something like that possible using Eigen build-in functions? If not what would be a nice way to accomplish this on my own? ( Defining my own iterator?)

Comment: I don't know if Eigen itself has something that would do this, but every time I want a custom iterator, I turn to `boost::iterator_facade` or `boost::iterator_adaptor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the `Eigen` documentation, but a simple forward iterator doesn't need too much:

- equality operators
- increment operators
- dereference operator

This is what I came up with

```cpp
template <Eigen::Index RowSize, Eigen::Index ColSize>
struct EigenBlockIt {
    using Self = EigenBlockIt<RowSize, ColSize>;

    // constructors for end()/begin() equivalents
    EigenBlockIt() : matrix(nullptr) , col(0), row(0) { }
    EigenBlockIt(const Eigen::MatrixXd& matrix) : matrix(&matrix) , col(0), row(0) { }

    // comparison
    friend bool operator ==(const Self& lhs, const Self& rhs) {
        return lhs.matrix == rhs.matrix && lhs.row == rhs.row && lhs.col == rhs.col;
    }
    friend bool operator !=(const Self& lhs, const Self& rhs) {
        return lhs.matrix != rhs.matrix || lhs.row != rhs.row || lhs.col != rhs.col;
    }

    // increment (postfix/prefix)
    Self& operator++() {
        row++;
        if (row >= matrix->rows() / RowSize) {
            row = 0;
            col++;
            if (col >= matrix->cols() / ColSize) {
                matrix = nullptr;
                row = 0;
                col = 0;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Self operator++(int) {
        EigenBlockIt it = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return it;
    }

    // dereference
    const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::MatrixXd, RowSize, ColSize> operator *() const {
        return matrix->block<RowSize, ColSize>((matrix->rows() / RowSize) * row, (matrix->cols() / ColSize) * col);
    }

    const Eigen::MatrixXd* matrix;
    Eigen::Index row;
    Eigen::Index col;
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
for (auto it = EigenBlockIt<2, 2>(A); it != EigenBlockIt<2, 2>(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/boz9xG

Comment: Thank you! I now also tried it out on my own: https://godbolt.org/z/qanxed Basically the dereference is missing in my example, the behavior for the end Iterator and the constness. In my example the end is just rows=4 and col=0 since this is one beyond the last block. But i think your example is more nice since you don't have to pass the matrix to the end iterator. What do you think about this or which is more kind of best pratice? Furthermore, i thought about a method to only pass the blocksize template parameters once to the begin iterator but i don't come up with result.

Comment: I think your code looks perfectly fine no obvious bugs. If you implement all the operators and the 5 typedefs (value_type, etc), then you can use the iterator with functions in `<algorithm>`. If not, then it's all style, and you can do whatever you think looks nice in your code.